# java --list-modules shows module, but jlink can't find it

Tags: java

I'm running JDK 13.

I'm trying to build a full JRE for the JDK 13.

Since my app has too many embeded jars and is not modular, using `jdeps` is too cumbersome, so I decided to just include all java modules in my custom jre.
The problem is that `jlink` can't find the modules from java itself.

This is the output from `java -version`:

```
openjdk version "13.0.2" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
```

This is the output from `java --list-modules`:

```
java.base@13.0.2
java.compiler@13.0.2
java.datatransfer@13.0.2
java.desktop@13.0.2
java.instrument@13.0.2
java.logging@13.0.2
java.management@13.0.2
java.management.rmi@13.0.2
java.naming@13.0.2
java.net.http@13.0.2
java.prefs@13.0.2
java.rmi@13.0.2
java.scripting@13.0.2
java.se@13.0.2
java.security.jgss@13.0.2
java.security.sasl@13.0.2
java.smartcardio@13.0.2
java.sql@13.0.2
java.sql.rowset@13.0.2
java.transaction.xa@13.0.2
java.xml@13.0.2
java.xml.crypto@13.0.2
jdk.accessibility@13.0.2
jdk.aot@13.0.2
jdk.attach@13.0.2
jdk.charsets@13.0.2
jdk.compiler@13.0.2
jdk.crypto.cryptoki@13.0.2
jdk.crypto.ec@13.0.2
jdk.crypto.mscapi@13.0.2
jdk.dynalink@13.0.2
jdk.editpad@13.0.2
jdk.hotspot.agent@13.0.2
jdk.httpserver@13.0.2
jdk.internal.ed@13.0.2
jdk.internal.jvmstat@13.0.2
jdk.internal.le@13.0.2
jdk.internal.opt@13.0.2
jdk.internal.vm.ci@13.0.2
jdk.internal.vm.compiler@13.0.2
jdk.internal.vm.compiler.management@13.0.2
jdk.jartool@13.0.2
jdk.javadoc@13.0.2
jdk.jcmd@13.0.2
jdk.jconsole@13.0.2
jdk.jdeps@13.0.2
jdk.jdi@13.0.2
jdk.jdwp.agent@13.0.2
jdk.jfr@13.0.2
jdk.jlink@13.0.2
jdk.jshell@13.0.2
jdk.jsobject@13.0.2
jdk.jstatd@13.0.2
jdk.localedata@13.0.2
jdk.management@13.0.2
jdk.management.agent@13.0.2
jdk.management.jfr@13.0.2
jdk.naming.dns@13.0.2
jdk.naming.rmi@13.0.2
jdk.net@13.0.2
jdk.pack@13.0.2
jdk.rmic@13.0.2
jdk.scripting.nashorn@13.0.2
jdk.scripting.nashorn.shell@13.0.2
jdk.sctp@13.0.2
jdk.security.auth@13.0.2
jdk.security.jgss@13.0.2
jdk.unsupported@13.0.2
jdk.unsupported.desktop@13.0.2
jdk.xml.dom@13.0.2
jdk.zipfs@13.0.2
```

As you guys can see, the module `jdk.jartool@13.0.2` is there.

But when I try to run `jlink` including all the modules, I get an error.

Here is the command I'm trying to run:

```
jlink --output jre --module-path ${JAVA_HOME}/jmods --add-modules \
java.base@13.0.2\
,java.compiler@13.0.2\
,java.datatransfer@13.0.2\
,java.desktop@13.0.2\
,java.instrument@13.0.2\
,java.logging@13.0.2\
,java.management@13.0.2\
,java.management.rmi@13.0.2\
,java.naming@13.0.2\
,java.net.http@13.0.2\
,java.prefs@13.0.2\
,java.rmi@13.0.2\
,java.scripting@13.0.2\
,java.se@13.0.2\
,java.security.jgss@13.0.2\
,java.security.sasl@13.0.2\
,java.smartcardio@13.0.2\
,java.sql@13.0.2\
,java.sql.rowset@13.0.2\
,java.transaction.xa@13.0.2\
,java.xml@13.0.2\
,java.xml.crypto@13.0.2\
,jdk.accessibility@13.0.2\
,jdk.aot@13.0.2\
,jdk.attach@13.0.2\
,jdk.charsets@13.0.2\
,jdk.compiler@13.0.2\
,jdk.crypto.cryptoki@13.0.2\
,jdk.crypto.ec@13.0.2\
,jdk.crypto.mscapi@13.0.2\
,jdk.dynalink@13.0.2\
,jdk.editpad@13.0.2\
,jdk.hotspot.agent@13.0.2\
,jdk.httpserver@13.0.2\
,jdk.internal.ed@13.0.2\
,jdk.internal.jvmstat@13.0.2\
,jdk.internal.le@13.0.2\
,jdk.internal.opt@13.0.2\
,jdk.internal.vm.ci@13.0.2\
,jdk.internal.vm.compiler@13.0.2\
,jdk.internal.vm.compiler.management@13.0.2\
,jdk.jartool@13.0.2\
,jdk.javadoc@13.0.2\
,jdk.jcmd@13.0.2\
,jdk.jconsole@13.0.2\
,jdk.jdeps@13.0.2\
,jdk.jdi@13.0.2\
,jdk.jdwp.agent@13.0.2\
,jdk.jfr@13.0.2\
,jdk.jlink@13.0.2\
,jdk.jshell@13.0.2\
,jdk.jsobject@13.0.2\
,jdk.jstatd@13.0.2\
,jdk.localedata@13.0.2\
,jdk.management@13.0.2\
,jdk.management.agent@13.0.2\
,jdk.management.jfr@13.0.2\
,jdk.naming.dns@13.0.2\
,jdk.naming.rmi@13.0.2\
,jdk.net@13.0.2\
,jdk.pack@13.0.2\
,jdk.rmic@13.0.2\
,jdk.scripting.nashorn@13.0.2\
,jdk.scripting.nashorn.shell@13.0.2\
,jdk.sctp@13.0.2\
,jdk.security.auth@13.0.2\
,jdk.security.jgss@13.0.2\
,jdk.unsupported@13.0.2\
,jdk.unsupported.desktop@13.0.2\
,jdk.xml.dom@13.0.2\
,jdk.zipfs@13.0.2
```

But when I run this command, I get this error:

```
Error: Module jdk.jartool@3.0.2 not found
```

I tried changing the module path to the java bin folder, to the lib folder, to JAVA_HOME only, but nothing seems to work, and if I remove the "missing" module, another one will be "missing".

I am using git bash to run the command under Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is due to the version syntax you're using with  `--add-modules`.

The following gives same error as you see above, albeit with a different Java version.

```
./bin/jlink.exe --output so-question-test --module-path jmods/ --add-modules jdk.jartool@11.0.2
Error: Module jdk.jartool@11.0.2 not found
```

However without `@11.0.2` the command completes without error

```
$ ./bin/jlink.exe --output so-question-test --module-path jmods/ --add-modules jdk.jartool
```

The [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm) for jlink doesn't appear to state that versioning is supported. Even if it were I could not see how this would work in practice given the .jmod files don't have the version in the filename i.e. the file in question is `$JAVA_HOME/jmods/jdk.jartool.jmod` not `$JAVA_HOME/jmods/jdk.jartool-11.0.2.jmod`

> module [,module...]
>
> The names of the modules to add to the runtime image. The jlink tool
>   adds these modules and their transitive dependencies.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! :D